# python print like this

Tags: python, pretty-print

I would like to print the following dictionary:

```
'test.com': {'@': {'NS': ['ns1.test.net', 'ns2.test.net']},
             'api': {'A': ['123.122.2.1','121.161.51.29','111.30.12.14']}}
```

Like the following:

```
'test.com': {
    '@': {
        'NS': ['ns1.test.net', 'ns2.test.net']
         },
    'api': {
        'A': ['123.122.2.1','121.161.51.29','111.30.12.14']
         }
 }
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow doesn't provide you code, but helps you if you have a problem when making your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution with `json`:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {'test.com': {'@': {'NS': ['ns1.test.net', 'ns2.test.net']}, 'api': {'A': ['123.122.2.1', '121.161.51.29', '111.30.12.14']}}}
>>> print json.dumps(data,indent=4)
{
    "test.com": {
        "@": {
            "NS": [
                "ns1.test.net", 
                "ns2.test.net"
            ]
        }, 
        "api": {
            "A": [
                "123.122.2.1", 
                "121.161.51.29", 
                "111.30.12.14"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Haidro .For python, I still have a lot to learn, thank you very much.Here, I can learn python , and also learn English.

Comment: @LeiWu I was not addressing you :p. Someone had voted my question down (pressed the down arrow) but not explained why.

Comment: @LeiWu Don't worry that question wasn't directed at you. Anyway here's an upvote

Comment: I understand that, but you've given me an idea, so I cast your votes。For others I was not very clear。Fortunately, there is a google translation。

Comment: @LeiWu As far as I know, you haven't done anything wrong, so there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module.

If you don't like the format the `pprint` provides, then you will need to write your own method for printing the object.

Comment: @LeiWu This is not an answer to your question. Don't accept it if it didn't help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just a novice, I will learn the rules.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yup, definitely not the answer you are looking for.